# I want to comment my python code and i Don't know what is the symbol of multiple line comment in python

Tags: python, comments

How do I make multi-lined comments in python?

My Code So Far:

```py
print("Hello world")
print("Hello universe")
print("Hello everyone")
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: """Try THIS""" over multiple lines ... Docstring ... can be used as comment (triple quotes).

Answer (score 1):

You can either paste `#` at the beginning of each row:

```
#print("Hello world")
#print("Hello universe")
#print("Hello everyone")
```

Or use this syntax:

```
"""print("Hello world")
print("Hello universe")
print("Hello everyone")"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Python does not have a syntax for multi-line comments.
The only thing you could do is comment on each and every line. Or you could do as Claudio said to use """Comments here""" for multi-lined comments.